# Find and Replace all words starting with # and wrap the hashtagged text in HTML

Tags: c#, regex, replace, find

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find my answer and I have been looking for sometime now. Using C# or a regular expression, I'm trying to find and replace all hashtagged words within a string and wrap them in HTML tags.

Example Input Text:

```
I would like to wrap #AllHashtags with html #Code to make it #StandOut
```

Ideal Output Text

```
I would like to wrap <span class="yellow">#AllHashtags</span> with html <span class="yellow">#Code</span> to make it <span class="yellow">#StandOut</span>
```

I've tried the following, but not luck

```
tweet.Text = "<span class='yellow'>" + tweet.Hashtags + "</span>";

tweet.Text.Replace("#", "<span class='yellow'>#");

tweet test = tweet.Text.IndexOf("#", 0);

var containsHastag = tweet.Text.Contains("#", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"#\w+", "<span class=\"yellow\">$&</span>");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%5Cw%2B&i=I%20would%20like%20to%20wrap%20%23AllHashtags%20with%20html%20%23Code%20to%20make%20it%20%23StandOut&r=%3Cspan%20class%3D%27yellow%27%3E%24%26%3C%2Fspan%3E)

The `#\w+` matches `#` and then 1 or more word chars (letters, digits, `_`, etc.) and `$&` references the whole match value (hence, no need using a capturing group around the whole regex pattern).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the demo as well. Much appreciated.